# Mensagem de erro ao criar novo Controller com Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Sou novo no `ASP.NET MVC` e estou com um problema. Quando eu tento adicionar um novo `Controller` usando Entity Framework dá um erro dizendo:

> erro ao executar o gerador de código selecionado: o valor -1 está fora
>   do intervalo aceitável

Eu procurei no Google e achei várias pessoas com erro ao executar o gerador de código, mas nenhum igual a mensagem que eu obtive. Alguém conseguiria me ajudar, por favor?

Estou utilizando `MySQL` e instalei todas bibliotecas possíveis relacionadas ao `MySQL` e `Entity Framework` do `MySQL`.

Comment: Bem vindo Gustavo. Qual a versão do Visual Studio? Quando adiciona o Controller quais configurações está usando para o scaffolding?

Comment: Acredito que a mensagem equivalente para seu erro em inglês é: "There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The value -1 is outside the acceptable range..."